# Solution of Pell equation over field of p-adic numbers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

Right now I am studying Pell equation. Using continued fractions, we can find the solution of Pell equation. Now my question, is it possible for me to 
find a solution in the field of p-adic numbers using continued fraction of p-adic numbers?
Anyone?

Comment: This proposes the developpement of "continued fractions over a field of $p$-adic numbers." I think additional conditions ought to be added.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do? Finding solutions to equation of the type $x^2-ny^2=1$ is relatively easy when one half of the $p$-adic integers have square roots in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Are you hoping to find all the solutions? That's a rational curve so there's bound to be a parametrization by rational functions of the solutions. So what's the goal here?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Thank you for the comment you are right this problem is just trivial since square root of a natural number is always inside in the valuation ring with uniformizer p(a prime). So if we factor the equation, we have a product of two p-adic integers which is equal to 1. Thus they are in the group of units of the p-adic valuation ring. The solutions (x,y) are easily found, the valuations of the two factors are just equal to 0. I thought I can do something about it by just  finding solutions using p-adic continued fraction, similar to real case.

Comment: Depends on the valuation ring. A natural number $n=p^am$ with $\gcd(p,m)=1$ has a square root in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, iff $a$ is even and $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. So what I said was wrong. Only a quarter (not one half!) of natural number have square roots in $\Bbb{Z}_p$. The remaining square roots are in an extension. Anyway, finding solutions to a Pell equation is easy enough, when you have two variables to work with.

Comment: p-adic continued fractions were studied by K. Mahler in _Zur Approximation P-adischer Irrationalzahlen_ and A. Ruban in _Certain metric properties of the p-adic numbers_. But the theory is somewhat unsatisfying, IMO, as the set of p-adic numbers with finite continued fraction does not form a ring (not even an additive group), and is unknown. I read somewhere that a characterization is known for p=2, but I don't recall where.

Answer (score 4):

I’m not well-enough read to tell you about the utility of continued fractions in the $p$-adic context; all I can do is point out that you can’t expect a continued fraction of the kind you’re used to from the solution of Pell’s equation that you know.

What makes the continued fraction process work in the real case? You have a little real number $\varepsilon$ that’s between $0$ and $1$. Then you take its reciprocal, and you get a big number. Then you subtract *just* the right positive integer to get a new little number $\varepsilon'$. And continue.

In the $p$-adic world, you can start with your little number $\varepsilon$, and take its reciprocal to get a big number, but the *whole point* of the nonarchimedean metric is that no integer will be anywhere near that big number. What are you going to subtract? There’s no natural, and certainly no unique, rational number that can stand as your partial quotient, the analog of the partial quotients that you see in continued fractions.

So the moral is that if you’re going to use continued fractions for any kind of approximative expansion of a quadratic irrationality in $\mathbb Z_p$ or $\mathbb Q_p$, the expressions will look very different, and I suspect that they will not be anywhere near as useful as in the real case.